# React native scroll sub column

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I have a View like this

```
<View style={styles.columnView}>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnC]}><Text></Text></View>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnA]}><Text></Text></View>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnB]}><Text></Text></View>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnE]}><Text>{value}</Text></View>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnAs]}><Text></Text></View>
  <View style={[styles.columnButtonItem, styles.columnT]}><Text></Text></View>
</View>
```

After iterations, I compose a table like this:

[image]

There is a way to add ScroolView on a single column?
For example, I want to enable scroll only on columnE.
Obviously, when i scroll columnE I want to scroll all the table.

Thanks

Comment: So do you want to scroll only column E or the entire table? :) Is it that you want to make the entire table scrollable only via column E?

Comment: I want to make the entire table scrollable only via column E

Comment: By chance you could put this in a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) so that I can provide a direct answer there? Even if you're not using Expo adding only the styling and layout should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Absolutely positioned Views

If you know the width of the columns then you could use Views that are absolutely positioned that overlap the underlying `ScrollView`, they would stop all touches to the `ScrollView`. Meaning that it would only scroll on the part that isn't covered by the absolutely positioned views.

So you could do something like this

```
render() {
  // set these widths to be the size before row E and the size after row E
  let leftWidth = '33%'; 
  let rightWidth = '33%';
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>

        // items for the scroll view go here

      </ScrollView>
      <View style={{position:'absolute', top:0, left: 0, bottom: 0, width: leftWidth}} />
      <View style={{position:'absolute', top:0, right: 0, bottom: 0, width: rightWidth}} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

## Snack

Here is a snack showing this implementation. I have set a `backgroundColor` on the absolutely positioned views so that you can clearly see them. 
https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/partial-scrollview

## Caveat

The main problem with this solution is that you will not be able to touch anything that is below the absolutely positioned views. You could mitigate that by capturing touches using [gestures](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system) on each `View` and then mapping them to positions on the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

I (think) this is what you're looking for... essentially you can only scroll the far right column and the rest of the columns are not scrollable. Because of that, you have to wait for the native event handler of ScrollView to propagate any change before you render the fact that the rest of those 4 columns are scrolling though.

https://snack.expo.io/@vincentvella/scroll-example